# How do I make pantheon-files works with newer version of tumbler?

Tags: pantheon-files

The old version of tumbler is way too old, the version is so old that it doesn't support the hevc or vp9 videos to generate thumbnails, I have successfully installed the newer version of tumbler(0.1.31), tumbler-common(0.1.31) and gstreamer1.0(1.4.3), how do I make pantheon-files works with it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have correctly installed the new version in the correct place, removed the old version and restarted the daemon (or the whole system) I do not think you have to do anything with Files.